# Regex negative lookahead to match url

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to match urls
/api/v1/users...
/api/v1/other_stuff...

Except for
/api/v1/users/invitation_register

I've been trying to use negative lookbehind

```
^\/api.*(?<!\binvitation_register\b)
```

and several similar constructs and have no idea how to actually do this.
Any help would be more then welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this negative lookahead instead of lookbehind:

```
^\/api\/(?!v1\/users\/invitation_register\b).*
```

`(?!v1\/users\/invitation_register\b)` is a **negative lookahead** that asserts that `v1/users/invitation_register` fails after `/api/`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qW4zW8/3)

If your intended match is always starting with `/api/v1/...` then you can use:

```
^\/api\/v1\/(?!users\/invitation_register\b).*
```

which asserts that `users/invitation_register` fails after `/api/va/`.

Comment: Dunno what's wrong, but maybe you might add a corrected version of the OPs regex (`^\/api(?!.*\binvitation_register\b).*`) and explain the mistakes (used lookahead not lookbehind, handling of .*)

Comment: There is no need to use `(?!.*\binvitation_register\b)` because all OP wants is to avoid `/api/v1/users/invitation_register` and `(?!.*\binvitation_register\b)` will also avoid `/api/v1/foobar/invitation_register`